# How much security is compromised if we accept other characters as login (other than the original password)?

Tags: cryptography, passwords, brute-force

I've just realised that facebook accepts 3 forms of a password:

[Source](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/facebook/facebook-passwords-are-not-case-sensitive-update/3612?tag=nl.e589):

> Facebook actually accepts three forms of your password:
>
> 1. Your original password.
> 2. Your original password with the first letter
>      capitalized. This is only for mobile devices, which sometimes
>      capitalize the first character of a word.
> 3. Your original password with
>      the case reversed, for those with a caps lock key on.

Obviously they are claiming that the security compromised is insignificant. My question is  is the security compromised really insignificant ?

How much easily is a hacker able to achieve a login with 2 additional "holes" ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These rules basically mean that instead of having one valid password for an account, there are three of them (two, if the original password already begins with an uppercase letter). Theoretically, this divides attacker effort by up to 3, but actually a bit less than that because "pASSWORD" is much less probable as a user-chosen password than "Password".

So, in short words: these rules make password-guessing attacks three times *easier*. This does not mean that they make attacks *easy*.

Comment: So, would it be fair to state that these rules lower the effective entropy by approximately 1.5 bits (all else being equal)?

Comment: That's three times easier to guess using their external login system. Brute-forcing would require the exact same amount of hashes, since their login mechanism likely takes the input password, transforms it, and hashes each version of it (for a total of three hashes to try three versions of the input password). Since they control the login system it would be difficult to use as an attack vector.

Comment: @AviD: about 1.585 bits, actually (logarithm of 3 in base 2).

Comment: @pdubs: if the attacker has the hashes of the three versions, he can still get the 3x factor: he "tries" only one version (e.g. "password" but not "Password" or "pASSWORD"). His goal is to have _one_ matching hash, any of the three will do.

Comment: @ThomasPornin I suppose that depends on the implementation. If there are three hashes stored in the DB, then the 3x applies, but if there is one hash in the DB and the login function hashes the input three times (after transforming the plaintext input), then the 3x exploit is limited to using the interface's login functionality, which is far from optimal for a brute-force attack and easily mitigated with a simple attempt limit.

Comment: @pdubs: there is a need for some formalism here. A password hashing scheme invokes the hash function _N_ times for each login attempt; _N_ is adjusted so that the process is slow, but not too slow on the server. If the server must hash three password variants, it will use _N/3_ hash invocations on each. If it accepted only a single password variant, it could afford to spend three times as many CPU on that, i.e. _N_ hash invocations on that unique password. This is where the 3x comes from: 3x weaker _for a given CPU budget on the server_.

Comment: In other words, a server can always increase the number of nested hash invocations on any hashed password: it increases attack cost by a factor of _x_, and usage cost by the same factor _x_. I am reasoning at constant usage cost.

Comment: perhaps they don't store 3 passwords: they can have some rule like "always consider the first letter to be lower-case" and "when pass is case-mixed, invert the case if there are more or = caps than lower-case letters". And this could be frightening

Comment: The three separate hashes of the three separate passwords can potentially be computed **in parallel**. With a good strategy, the time to compute three hashes can be nearly identical to the time to compute one hash for each login attempt. Thus if, as a business requirement on perceived performance, the time budget for a login attempt is `<= 75ms`, then that can remain the time budget for a login attempt even if three hashes must be computed, without reducing the hardness (number of iterations) of the hash.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is correct. It's an insignificant decrease in security for an enormous increase in usability.

Even making passwords a million times easier to guess isn't a big problem. That's what many other sites do. To solve the same problem, they simply treat all upper and lower case the same. That means a 9 letter password will have a million combinations, and thus will become a million times easier to guess.

While these sorts of things make passwords "weaker", websites can do things to make passwords "stronger". One way is to enforce minimal password lengths, or force users to include punctuation/numbers. Another way is "key strengthening", or repeatedly hashing a password many times. For example, some sites hash the password 1000 times, making it 1000 times harder to crack.

Some people choose easy passwords like "123456" that can be guessed no matter how strong the system is. Likewise, some people choose passwords like "#hd&G!!nv*63" that cannot be guessed, not matter how weak the system is. Making the system a million times stronger or a million times weaker only protects/endangers the tiny number of passwords on the edge between the two.

Comment: with a strong hash, I believe hashing a password 1000 times doesn't make it any more than hashing it once right?